# FastAPI: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn'

Tags: python, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I will admit I never used `gunicorn` before. When I run the command `gunicorn  main:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` gives error:

```
Error: class uri 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker' invalid or not found: 

[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 135, in load_class
    mod = import_module('.'.join(components))
  File "/Users/X/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn'
```

Comment: Did you install uvicorn? (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#requirements) It isn't an explicit dependency of FastAPI or gunicorn, but it's one of the workers for running FastAPI.

Comment: @GinoMempin both `uvicorn` and `gunicorn` are installed as I am already able to use `uvicorn main:app --reload`

Comment: @GinoMempin I found the issue. I just did `which gunicorn` and turns out is not using the one in my `venv` which sounds strange rather the one in host machine. What should I do?

Comment: Uninstall the one outside the venv, you probably installed it system-wide, and the binary `gunicorn` is available at the beginning of your `PATH`. Uninstall it then make sure it's properly installed and accessible on your venv. (And make sure you are actually using the venv.)

Comment: @GinoMempin it was shipped or installed with `conda`.

Comment: you can just run the correct one from the terminal depending on where your venv is located, i.e. `env/bin/gunicorn  main:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` if your env folder is in the root of your project

Comment: I am having the exact issue...

Comment: in my case, I installed gunicorn globally with `apt-get`, it did not work. then I did `conda install gunicorn` again, this time it installed in my current conda env and it started working.

Comment: hit the same issue again 2nd time~! Adding one more case: even after I installed `gunicorn` I was still getting the missing `uvicorn` issue. Then I found uvicorn was not installed under my current conda env. so I installed it: `conda install -c conda-forge uvicorn`

Comment: @Franva for me it was the path issue.

Answer (score 12):

Check if you are calling the correct Gunicorn using `which gunicorn` (on Linux, or use `where` on Powerbash from Windows) from the terminal. If you are using a venv it should print a path pointing inside your venv directory.

It happend to me also, because I followed the instruction from the Gunicorn page and installed using `sudo apt install gunicorn`. It could be a good option for your production container, where you'll probably run the application without a venv, but in developer mode on you machine it will work better if you install gunicorn inside your venv directory using the `pip install gunicorn`, using the `pip` from your venv.

Then you can call it with `python -m gunicorn main:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

Comment: Why does it work ? Any possible explanations

Answer (score 3):

The `ModuleNotFoundError` you're seeing means that Python cannot find the uvicorn module, which is a web server for ASGI (Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface) applications. This error can occur for a few different reasons:

- The uvicorn module is not installed on your system. You can install it using `pip install uvicorn`.
- You are running an older version of Python that does not have uvicorn installed. `uvicorn` requires Python 3.6 or later.
- You are trying to import uvicorn in the wrong way. You should be able to import it by adding import uvicorn at the top of your Python file.
- If you're still having trouble, it would be helpful to see the code you're trying to run and any additional error messages you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The FastApi docs I had to install `uvicorn` separately, so

This didn't work:

```bash
poetry add "fastapi[uvicorn]"
# you won't see uvicorn in the logs
```

This worked

```bash
poetry add fastapi uvicorn
# you can see in the logs uvicorn is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding PYTHONPATH to your environment variables with `$ export PYTHONPATH=$PWD` in unix based OS.
It did solve a similar issue I had.